# Обработка щелка строки Listbox

Tags: ооп, события, delphi, delphi-7

Какое событие отвечает за обработку щелчка мыши по строке в Listbox? Необходимо по щелчку мыши по строке в ListBox создать окно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OnClick** или **OnDblClick** для двойного клика, а узнать на какой именно строке клик был
**ListBox.ItemIndex**